# Set GRUB2 to boot from a .vmdk file

Tags: grub2

So, basically I have installed Windows 7 in a Virtual Machine, and I want to boot the Virtual Machine's hard drive up on my PC, my [grub2](http://download1483.mediafire.com/7ulj6c084vhg/ar1up99q2uhvtqk/grub.cfg) and [40_config](http://download1482.mediafire.com/f9845440mstg/2tzd47xtera4k6z/40_custom) files can be found by clicking those hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is primarily a VMWare question?  They do have procedures to facilitate this, although you may find that you would need to do some reconfiguration.  [This link](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/disks_dualboot_ws.html) is from a slightly older version of VMWare Workstation, and describes how the ability to either dual boot into an OS, or run the OS as a virtual machine might be done.